# How can data URLs be exploited?

Tags: web-application

I found I can upload an avatar using data URL (the one you get by googling some picture and right-clicking on its miniature) by just changing **type="file"** to **type="url"**. Initially user shouldn't be able to perfom this action. The data URL looks like this: **data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/[lots of random letters and digits]** How can this vulnerability be exploited?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look up SQL Injection, XSS, etc. It's possible these attacks could work against the url if the program is incorrectly handling the user input.

Answer (score 1):

[Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is a standard for embedding the data you want to use directly within your page (that is - not be in need to use an external file). This is handled by the browser and is essentially a Base64 version of the binary file (a picture in your case).

So, client wise, you are as safe as your browser is.

I did not fully understand your question but you are asking whether such an encoding schema can be used to push malicious payload to a server - probably yes. It all depends on how whatever is received by the web application is later processed. There is nothing like a "generic exploit" in that case and the Base64 data you send are not special per se.